# Google websites are broken on chrome but not firefox

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, google-chrome, youtube

I don't know how to explain it properly but I have some issues with a lot of websites when I navigate.
It is buggy on all my google websites, I can't read a video on youtube, i don't see some icons on gmail / calendar / drive...

However when I navigate with firefox it is working perfectly.

When I look in console, I always have CORS errors on my js :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://r2---sn-25ge7nsd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mt=1551127153&mv=m&ei=-FJ0XPyyDZKPhAeypaXwCQ&ms=au%2Conr&requiressl=yes&gir=yes&mm=31%2C26&clen=5253281&mn=sn-hgn7rn7k%2Csn-25ge7nsd&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&mime=audio%2Fwebm&txp=3411222&itag=250&pl=23&signature=BB21202C8C649B9E3149B9788428D6F628C25CCD.1A0F575420E5DB60FA85187ECD09AFB352E2D71C&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&ipbits=0&source=youtube&initcwndbps=1202500&fvip=2&id=o-ADr-nCfQ6uY_A5fz1e-CF1abWcbnvMsW6sXJeepykdHm&ip=80.236.19.94&key=yt6&lmt=1551124542054840&dur=662.481&expire=1551148888&alr=yes&cpn=vKd_QsmqKewPYaFF&cver=2.20190221&fallback_count=1&range=0-1401&rn=5&rbuf=0' from origin 'https://www.youtube.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I provide some console dumps if it helps

on youtube :

```
    <link rel=preload> must have a valid `as` value
VM231 watch:19 GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
(anonymous) @ VM231 watch:19
VM231 watch:19 GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
(anonymous) @ VM231 watch:19
[Deprecation] HTML Imports is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use ES modules instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376 for more details.
2VM224 watch:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: A network error occurred.
base.js:1120 GET https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id net::ERR_FAILED
Zq @ base.js:1120
g.Yq @ base.js:1105
(anonymous) @ base.js:1145
g.Mg @ base.js:345
yr @ base.js:1142
Yda @ base.js:1156
Kr @ base.js:1161
Dia @ base.js:2557
jK.fetch @ base.js:5379
g.h.Kp @ base.js:5592
g.h.Cm @ base.js:5638
xO @ base.js:2945
(anonymous) @ base.js:2939
Hg @ base.js:342
Promise.then (async)
Dg @ base.js:341
g.Gg @ base.js:340
ch @ base.js:366
Lg @ base.js:361
(anonymous) @ base.js:345
f @ base.js:352
(anonymous) @ base.js:68
k @ base.js:364
Promise.then (async)
paa @ base.js:365
Sg @ base.js:362
Tg @ base.js:350
(anonymous) @ base.js:352
g.Mg @ base.js:345
g.Vg @ base.js:352
Fz @ base.js:1664
Mfa @ base.js:1662
(anonymous) @ base.js:1811
Ar.then @ base.js:4435
g.wB @ base.js:1811
jia @ base.js:2342
FI @ base.js:2425
wia @ base.js:2424
g.h.Ro @ base.js:5268
EI @ base.js:2422
II @ base.js:2426
eX @ base.js:3684
ela @ base.js:3682
MW @ base.js:3657
(anonymous) @ base.js:6556
ytplayer.load @ VM235 watch:55
(anonymous) @ VM235 watch:55
(anonymous) @ VM235 watch:55
VM224 watch:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id' from origin 'https://www.youtube.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field X-Client-Data is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
desktop_polymer.js:23 [Deprecation] document.registerElement is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use window.customElements.define instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4642138092470272 for more details.
(anonymous) @ desktop_polymer.js:23
(anonymous) @ desktop_polymer.js:24
desktop_polymer.js:1598 GET https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id net::ERR_FAILED
On @ desktop_polymer.js:1598
Kn @ desktop_polymer.js:1584
(anonymous) @ desktop_polymer.js:9341
Sw @ desktop_polymer.js:3150
gV @ desktop_polymer.js:9338
pV @ desktop_polymer.js:9353
tV @ desktop_polymer.js:9358
K2 @ desktop_polymer.js:10356
created @ desktop_polymer.js:14345
__initialize @ desktop_polymer.js:13
Polymer.Base.attributeChangedCallback @ desktop_polymer.js:20
Lp.Polymer.Base.attributeChangedCallback @ desktop_polymer.js:1718
(anonymous) @ watch?v=HX-wYOwICq8:200
J @ scheduler.js:21
O @ scheduler.js:26
F.J @ scheduler.js:24
(anonymous) @ web-animations-next-lite.min.js:96
requestAnimationFrame (async)
window.requestAnimationFrame @ web-animations-next-lite.min.js:96
F.start @ scheduler.js:27
O @ scheduler.js:26
F.J @ scheduler.js:24
(anonymous) @ web-animations-next-lite.min.js:96
requestAnimationFrame (async)
window.requestAnimationFrame @ web-animations-next-lite.min.js:96
F.start @ scheduler.js:27
K @ scheduler.js:18
ca @ scheduler.js:32
d.addJob @ desktop_polymer.js:1631
d.addMediumPriorityJob @ desktop_polymer.js:1625
d.applyScheduledSelectiveRegistration_ @ desktop_polymer.js:1881
(anonymous) @ desktop_polymer.js:1902
(anonymous) @ desktop_polymer.js:8373
(anonymous) @ desktop_polymer.js:14429
watch?v=HX-wYOwICq8:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id' from origin 'https://www.youtube.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field X-Client-Data is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
network.js:15 [Deprecation] chrome.loadTimes() is deprecated, instead use standardized API: nextHopProtocol in Navigation Timing 2. https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5637885046816768.
g.onreadystatechange @ network.js:15
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
ja @ network.js:16
request @ network.js:26
(anonymous) @ desktop_polymer.js:12480
Sw @ desktop_polymer.js:3150
d7 @ desktop_polymer.js:12477
b7 @ desktop_polymer.js:12476
a7 @ desktop_polymer.js:12475
postData @ desktop_polymer.js:14192
makeNextContinuationRequest_ @ desktop_polymer.js:11413
(anonymous) @ desktop_polymer.js:11412
onRetrieveLocation_ @ desktop_polymer.js:12178
handler @ desktop_polymer.js:166
e @ desktop_polymer.js:1719
fire @ desktop_polymer.js:196
onLoadNextContinuation_ @ desktop_polymer.js:11412
handler @ desktop_polymer.js:166
e @ desktop_polymer.js:1719
fire @ desktop_polymer.js:196
trigger @ desktop_polymer.js:11424
onShow @ desktop_polymer.js:11423
traverseNodes_ @ desktop_polymer.js:14210
traverseNodes_ @ desktop_polymer.js:14210
traverseNodes_ @ desktop_polymer.js:14210
traverseNodes_ @ desktop_polymer.js:14210
traverseNodes_ @ desktop_polymer.js:14210
traverseNodes_ @ desktop_polymer.js:14210
refreshVisibility_ @ desktop_polymer.js:14206
runVisibilityJob_ @ desktop_polymer.js:14202
(anonymous) @ desktop_polymer.js:1723
_flushRenderCallbacks @ desktop_polymer.js:11
(anonymous) @ desktop_polymer.js:10
setTimeout (async)
_flushNextRender @ desktop_polymer.js:10
fn @ desktop_polymer.js:10
(anonymous) @ web-animations-next-lite.min.js:96
requestAnimationFrame (async)
window.requestAnimationFrame @ web-animations-next-lite.min.js:96
_watchNextRender @ desktop_polymer.js:10
afterNextRender @ desktop_polymer.js:9
Lp.n.afterNextRender @ desktop_polymer.js:1723
created @ desktop_polymer.js:12367
__initialize @ desktop_polymer.js:13
Polymer.Base.attributeChangedCallback @ desktop_polymer.js:20
Lp.Polymer.Base.attributeChangedCallback @ desktop_polymer.js:1718
(anonymous) @ watch?v=HX-wYOwICq8:200
J @ scheduler.js:21
O @ scheduler.js:26
F.J @ scheduler.js:24
(anonymous) @ web-animations-next-lite.min.js:96
requestAnimationFrame (async)
window.requestAnimationFrame @ web-animations-next-lite.min.js:96
F.start @ scheduler.js:27
O @ scheduler.js:26
F.J @ scheduler.js:24
(anonymous) @ web-animations-next-lite.min.js:96
requestAnimationFrame (async)
window.requestAnimationFrame @ web-animations-next-lite.min.js:96
F.start @ scheduler.js:27
K @ scheduler.js:18
ca @ scheduler.js:32
d.addJob @ desktop_polymer.js:1631
d.addMediumPriorityJob @ desktop_polymer.js:1625
d.applyScheduledSelectiveRegistration_ @ desktop_polymer.js:1881
(anonymous) @ desktop_polymer.js:1902
(anonymous) @ desktop_polymer.js:8373
(anonymous) @ desktop_polymer.js:14429
fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4EsA.woff2:1 GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4EsA.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
The resource https://r2---sn-hgn7rn7k.googlevideo.com/generate_204?conn2 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
The resource https://r2---sn-hgn7rn7k.googlevideo.com/generate_204 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
base.js:2086 GET https://r2---sn-25glen7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?keepalive=yes&signature=0E242A739859EEE1E414488402180E838054AED4.A85D8BE82AF6011078453A90813EC33DA71CEBE3&mt=1551127008&dur=662.461&mime=video%2Fwebm&itag=278&expire=1551148716&mn=sn-hgn7rn7k%2Csn-25glen7r&mm=31%2C26&source=youtube&gir=yes&ip=80.236.19.94&fvip=2&pl=23&mv=m&ipbits=0&ms=au%2Conr&ei=TFJ0XKa2B47mxwLWr7OwDw&id=o-AJeTkDr5uBJCYLXuhOTDd-xMxeU0r-d5mpF3cXiVzB7k&txp=3431432&c=WEB&initcwndbps=1051250&key=yt6&lmt=1551120959585242&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278%2C298%2C299%2C302%2C303&requiressl=yes&clen=7620975&sparams=aitags%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&alr=yes&cpn=YGTEbajOWcp6lP2D&cver=2.20190221&fallback_count=1&range=0-4095&rn=3&rbuf=0 net::ERR_FAILED
LE @ base.js:2086
nha @ base.js:2099
g.h.start @ base.js:5140
CG @ base.js:2235
FG @ base.js:2239
g.h.NJ @ base.js:5166
g.h.nL @ base.js:5147
g.h.Mv @ base.js:4366
setTimeout (async)
g.hh @ base.js:373
g.h.start @ base.js:4363
g.h.nL @ base.js:5147
g.h.Mv @ base.js:4366
setTimeout (async)
g.hh @ base.js:373
g.h.start @ base.js:4363
g.h.nL @ base.js:5147
g.h.Mv @ base.js:4366
setTimeout (async)
g.hh @ base.js:373
g.h.start @ base.js:4363
g.h.start @ base.js:5140
CG @ base.js:2235
(anonymous) @ base.js:2267
g.A @ base.js:3839
QG @ base.js:2267
g.h.initialize @ base.js:5162
g.eJ @ base.js:2467
g.h.jJ @ base.js:5276
e.l @ base.js:358
eh @ base.js:369
bh @ base.js:368
g.Mg.D @ base.js:3908
Hg @ base.js:342
Promise.then (async)
Dg @ base.js:341
g.Gg @ base.js:340
ch @ base.js:366
Lg @ base.js:361
(anonymous) @ base.js:345
f @ base.js:352
(anonymous) @ base.js:68
k @ base.js:364
Promise.then (async)
paa @ base.js:365
Sg @ base.js:362
Tg @ base.js:350
(anonymous) @ base.js:352
g.Mg @ base.js:345
g.Vg @ base.js:352
Fz @ base.js:1664
Mfa @ base.js:1662
(anonymous) @ base.js:1811
Ar.then @ base.js:4435
g.wB @ base.js:1811
jia @ base.js:2342
FI @ base.js:2425
wia @ base.js:2424
g.h.Ro @ base.js:5268
EI @ base.js:2422
II @ base.js:2426
eX @ base.js:3684
ela @ base.js:3682
MW @ base.js:3657
(anonymous) @ base.js:6556
ytplayer.load @ watch?v=HX-wYOwICq8:55
(anonymous) @ watch?v=HX-wYOwICq8:55
(anonymous) @ watch?v=HX-wYOwICq8:55
watch?v=HX-wYOwICq8:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://r2---sn-25glen7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?keepalive=yes&signature=0E242A739859EEE1E414488402180E838054AED4.A85D8BE82AF6011078453A90813EC33DA71CEBE3&mt=1551127008&dur=662.461&mime=video%2Fwebm&itag=278&expire=1551148716&mn=sn-hgn7rn7k%2Csn-25glen7r&mm=31%2C26&source=youtube&gir=yes&ip=80.236.19.94&fvip=2&pl=23&mv=m&ipbits=0&ms=au%2Conr&ei=TFJ0XKa2B47mxwLWr7OwDw&id=o-AJeTkDr5uBJCYLXuhOTDd-xMxeU0r-d5mpF3cXiVzB7k&txp=3431432&c=WEB&initcwndbps=1051250&key=yt6&lmt=1551120959585242&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278%2C298%2C299%2C302%2C303&requiressl=yes&clen=7620975&sparams=aitags%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&alr=yes&cpn=YGTEbajOWcp6lP2D&cver=2.20190221&fallback_count=1&range=0-4095&rn=3&rbuf=0' from origin 'https://www.youtube.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

on google calendar I have this in my console :

```
m=base:438 GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/googlesans/v11/4UabrENHsxJlGDuGo1OIlLU94YtzCwY.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
Mm @ m=base:438
Ro @ m=base:540
To @ m=base:542
Zxa @ m=base:727
kra @ m=base:557
mra @ m=base:564
g.$V @ m=base:560
(anonymous) @ m=base:761
m=base:438 GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
Mm @ m=base:438
Ro @ m=base:540
To @ m=base:542
Zxa @ m=base:727
kra @ m=base:557
mra @ m=base:564
g.$V @ m=base:560
(anonymous) @ m=base:761
m=base:438 GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc4.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
Mm @ m=base:438
Ro @ m=base:540
To @ m=base:542
Zxa @ m=base:727
kra @ m=base:557
mra @ m=base:564
g.$V @ m=base:560
(anonymous) @ m=base:761
22?hl=fr:541 GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/productsans/v9/pxiDypQkot1TnFhsFMOfGShVF9eO.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
Fi @ 22?hl=fr:541
X @ 22?hl=fr:530
(anonymous) @ 22?hl=fr:552
(anonymous) @ 22?hl=fr:564
22?hl=fr:541 GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
Fi @ 22?hl=fr:541
X @ 22?hl=fr:530
(anonymous) @ 22?hl=fr:552
(anonymous) @ 22?hl=fr:564
22?hl=fr:541 GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc4.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
Fi @ 22?hl=fr:541
X @ 22?hl=fr:530
(anonymous) @ 22?hl=fr:552
(anonymous) @ 22?hl=fr:564
22?hl=fr:541 GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
Fi @ 22?hl=fr:541
X @ 22?hl=fr:530
(anonymous) @ 22?hl=fr:552
(anonymous) @ 22?hl=fr:564
222?hl=fr:566 GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialiconsextended/v47/kJEjBvgX7BgnkSrUwT8UnLVc38YydejYY-oE_LvJ.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:282 POST https://ogs.google.com/u/0/_/og/botguard/get?rt=j&sourceid=24 net::ERR_FAILED
(anonymous) @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:282
_.wf @ 22?hl=fr:417
_.tq @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:281
_.vq @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:280
_.it @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:362
vt @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:552
ut @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:548
tt.M @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:548
tt.start @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:547
(anonymous) @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:553
(anonymous) @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:560
22?hl=fr:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ogs.google.com/u/0/_/og/botguard/get?rt=j&sourceid=24' from origin 'https://calendar.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:282 POST https://ogs.google.com/u/0/_/notifications/count net::ERR_FAILED
(anonymous) @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:282
_.wf @ 22?hl=fr:417
_.tq @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:281
_.vq @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:280
_.it @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:362
pD.get @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:402
(anonymous) @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:418
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:418
(anonymous) @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:418
(anonymous) @ rs=AA2YrTvjOA8XfrGDZvkEiHw23SboGhkDGA:560
22?hl=fr:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ogs.google.com/u/0/_/notifications/count' from origin 'https://calendar.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
m=pjCC5c,KQU6nb,WPMVhf,RWEy5c,NJddyf,syan,UDuglb,SUIuyf,Uvgt5d,sy6m,zfqS6b,sy6p,sy6q,sy6o,sy6s,sy6r,sy6t,sy6v,sy6b,sy6g,sy6h,sy6i,sy6j,sy6u,sy6w,sy6z,lateload:169 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. 
aUa @ m=pjCC5c,KQU6nb,WPMVhf,RWEy5c,NJddyf,syan,UDuglb,SUIuyf,Uvgt5d,sy6m,zfqS6b,sy6p,sy6q,sy6o,sy6s,sy6r,sy6t,sy6v,sy6b,sy6g,sy6h,sy6i,sy6j,sy6u,sy6w,sy6z,lateload:169
cUa @ m=pjCC5c,KQU6nb,WPMVhf,RWEy5c,NJddyf,syan,UDuglb,SUIuyf,Uvgt5d,sy6m,zfqS6b,sy6p,sy6q,sy6o,sy6s,sy6r,sy6t,sy6v,sy6b,sy6g,sy6h,sy6i,sy6j,sy6u,sy6w,sy6z,lateload:168
(anonymous) @ m=pjCC5c,KQU6nb,WPMVhf,RWEy5c,NJddyf,syan,UDuglb,SUIuyf,Uvgt5d,sy6m,zfqS6b,sy6p,sy6q,sy6o,sy6s,sy6r,sy6t,sy6v,sy6b,sy6g,sy6h,sy6i,sy6j,sy6u,sy6w,sy6z,lateload:177
ip.execute @ m=base:556
jra @ m=base:557
kra @ m=base:557
kp.H @ m=base:564
(anonymous) @ m=pjCC5c,KQU6nb,WPMVhf,RWEy5c,NJddyf,syan,UDuglb,SUIuyf,Uvgt5d,sy6m,zfqS6b,sy6p,sy6q,sy6o,sy6s,sy6r,sy6t,sy6v,sy6b,sy6g,sy6h,sy6i,sy6j,sy6u,sy6w,sy6z,lateload:179
/_/scs/social-static/_/js/k=boq.SocialPeopleHovercardUi.fr.AiurMBcXtTY.O/rt=j/d=1/excm=hovercardwidget,_b,_tp/ed=1/dg=0/rs=AGLTcCN_kTuZParZu8gvA1dxDLK_1R17ZQ/m=_b,_tp:114 GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
```

Answer (score 3):

I found it by myself,
I had activated this parameter which breaks some stuff :
Out of blink CORS
CORS handling logic is moved out of blink. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android

## out-of-blink-cors

to solve it, we should go to chrome://flags and edit it to default